# error in summarizing data using Pandas_profiling

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to use the pandas_profiling ProfileReport method

`from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`
`ProfileReport(data)`

i have tried updating the jupyter,pandas and python through conda but I am still getting the following error:

`BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.`

this is the structure of the data:

````
RangeIndex: 32593 entries, 0 to 32592
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                --------------  ----- 
 0   code_module           32593 non-null  object
 1   code_presentation     32593 non-null  object
 2   id_student            32593 non-null  int64 
 3   gender                32593 non-null  object
 4   region                32593 non-null  object
 5   highest_education     32593 non-null  object
 6   imd_band              31482 non-null  object
 7   age_band              32593 non-null  object
 8   num_of_prev_attempts  32593 non-null  int64 
 9   studied_credits       32593 non-null  int64 
 10  disability            32593 non-null  object
 11  final_result          32593 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(3), object(9)
memory usage: 3.0+ MB```
````

Comment: it seems that your `data` may be more complex than the libraries (specifically [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)) can handle by default. can you show us some of that data? Don't put it in a comment -- update your question.

Comment: sure! i have modified the question to contain the data structure